# Não consigo obter o tamanho do arquivo

Tags: phonegap-buillder

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema no meu código ele não consegue entrar na função para obter o tamanho do arquivo, estou usando o Phonegap para desenvolvimento, segue o código abaixo

```
function onSuccess(imageData) {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageData, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            if (file.size > 2097152) {
                alert("não pode ser maior que 2mb");
            } else {
             //aqui vai o codigo para mostrar a imagem   

            }
        }, function (evt) {

        });
    },
    function () {

    });
   }
```

Então, estou tentando o obter o tamanho do arquivo mas ele não entra na função , não mostra nada, alguém sabe me dizer o problema ou estou fazendo errado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar `file.files[0].size` no lugar de `file.size`

Comment: Pois é ele não chega nem entrar no if, não entra na função fileEntry.file(function (file) e nem na função function (fileEntry) { como se ele não reconhecesse ela

Comment: Dei um debug aqui e alterei a linha `file(function (file) {` para `files(function (file) {` e não acusou mais erros.

Comment: Tá vou tentar dessa maneira

Comment: Não funcionou, não entra  na função function (fileEntry) {

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema eu concatenei com 'file:///'+imageData e o caminho ficou correto